# which cannot be treated as the friend in contrast with oops

Tags: java, c++, oop

i need your help in understanding a question.

which of these cannot be treated as the friend in contrast with oop:

1. Function
2. Class
3. Object
4. Operator function

> i think answer should be Operator function but i am not sure.please
>   anyone explain this to me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You're thinking wrong. Operator functions are friended all the time in c++. Also note, that not all of the languages you tagged here support that feature.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ OK! so what should be right answer??

Comment: Is this so hard to look up?

Comment: this might help you   http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object.

An object is instantiated, the others are not.

Think about what 'friend' means. It's like schema, you're defining access, but it's all done at compile time... an object is a run time thing so friendship is meaningless and uninforcable. Once your code is compiled it's all reduced to pointers and references and no checks are done.

Also, to further clarify, to create friendship relationships between objects and other objects, or between objects and anything else, you couldn't do that at compile/code time, as you don't know what objects will exist and you can't reference them... Such behaviour, or similar behaviour anyway, COULD be implemented by a language, but the friendships would have to be added at run time, and this would be quite an interesting feature of a high level language, but quite a different feature to friendship as we know it.

Comment: Think about what 'friend' means. It's like schema, you're defining access, but it's all done at compile time... an object is a run time thing so friendship is meaningless and uninforcable. Once your code is compiled it's all reduced to pointers and references and no checks are done.

Comment: Also, to further clarify, to create friendship relationships between objects and other objects, or between objects and anything else, you couldn't do that at compile/code time, as you don't know what objects will exist and you can't reference them... Such behaviour, or similar behaviour anyway, COULD be implemented by a language, but the friendships would have to be added at run time, and this would be quite an interesting feature of a high level language, but quite a different feature to friendship as we know it.

Comment: Added comments to answer, since comments are limited life.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your question makes only sense for C++.
2. `friend` is not a contrast to OOP. `friend` **helps** OOP by allowing you to expose fewer member variables and member functions. `friend` allows you to expose your `private` members to one particular external component. Without `friend`, you would have to make the members `public` and expose them to the whole world.
3. Objects cannot be made friends. `friend` is a mechanism to control member access and hence, like `public`, `protected` and `private` specifiers, a **compile-time** issue. Objects, in contrast, exist a **run-time**<sup>[*]</sup>.
4. An "operator function" (the correct word would be "overloaded operator") is **not that much different from a normal function**, really. You can mostly consider overloaded operators as functions with funny names. As far as `friend` is concerned, there is no difference whether you call your function `Add` or `+`, for example.

---

<sup>[*]</sup> I realise that this is a slight oversimplification when you consider template metapropgramming or `constexpr`.